# Silly question about the definition of Sum of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> **Definition**: Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{W}$ subspaces of $\mathcal{V}$.
>
> The set:
>
> $$\mathcal{U}+\mathcal{W} := \{u \boxplus w : u\in \mathcal{U},w\in \mathcal{W} \}$$
>
> Is called the SUM of subspaces $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{W}$.

My question is, obviously the element $u \boxplus w$ have a notion of sum given by the definition of $\boxplus$. But before we prove if the SUM is indeed a subspace of $\mathcal{V}$, the binary operation $\boxplus$ is the operation defined in $\mathcal{V}$? I mean $u \boxplus w \equiv u \boxplus_{\mathcal{V}} w$ ?

(*) The symbol $\boxplus$ is the vector adition. And the other symbol $\boxplus_{\mathcal{V}}$ is the vector adition defined specifically in the vector space $\mathcal{V}$

Comment: What is $\boxplus$? If not provided, then we cannot know.

Comment: Is a notion of vector adition. But I don't know if is the same notion of vector adition defined in $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: @xbh is it the same?

Comment: You are right. The addition is just the addition on $V$.

Comment: @JackClerk Actually I don't know, cause symbols without clarification could mean anything. But I may guess this is just the addition on $V$ [but I cannot say for sure, maybe check your textbook].

Comment: @xbh Maybe James have already answer my question, but I going to edit here.

Comment: Just the addition of vectors in $V$. Well-defined since $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$.

Comment: are you referring to the notation $\oplus$ ?

Comment: @Jneven Direct Sum notation? No.
I like to write $\boxplus_{V}$ and $\boxdot_{V}$ to operations defined in a vector space, respectively called Vector adition and Scalar Multiplication.
And for operations defined in Fields I like to write $+_{\mathbb{F}}$ and $\cdot_{\mathbb{F}}$, respectively called adition and multiplication.

Comment: with what properties? what is the meaning of those vector spaces?